# Sometimes, I don't see the button to Click for accepting answers

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Sometimes, I want to accept the answer to a question I posted but, I can't find the buttons that I'll click to do that. I'm kinda new and I want to know why?

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: Those are comments, not answers.

Comment: ^ This is likely the answer to the actual problem you are having, yet it's posted as comment, therefore treated like comment.

Comment: OK, thanks. Just like the ones you just posted, now? @Braiam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[That question from September 25th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413209/handling-backgroundworkers-reportprogress-event) doesn't have any answers. What you posted in your screenshot is just the question body and some comments. (Since they're only comments, they cannot be accepted or downvoted.) If some of the comments do answer your question you should:

1. Encourage the commenter to post a full answer that you can accept.
2. If they decline to answer, post your own answer explaining that the comment led you in the right direction.

Either way, that question could also use some improvement. It's not clear exactly what you're asking, and you should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Or just delete the question. At -3 it doesn't look like the community regard it as a good Q worth keeping around.

Comment: I don't know anything about the technology, but it seems fairly clear what the question is asking to me. It also doesn't seem to need an MCVE, though that may help to clarify the question... and frankly voting does not really represent whether a question is any good anymore. Reasonable questions are frequently downvoted and closed erroneously nowadays. cc@MartinSmith